# GRPC Google Example - Won't Import packages

Tags: dart, grpc

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8LDV.png)

[Google code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESgzj.png)

The google paths do not work, I CAN get intrafolder imports working, but nothing from outside. Added the name from pubspec, not importing. Any ideas, I am rapidly going insane! The first package import is the google code not edited, second is me trying to get it to work.

Comment: What is the value of `name` in your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: I don't know why using the full path with pubspec yaml name after : does not work.

Comment: Can you answer my question?

Comment: hi @julemand101 its 'grpc'

Comment: sorry, it's 'helloworld'

Comment: I have zero issues on my other flutter projects with this, is it because this google example has multiple pubspec.yaml files?